# Keep textbox protected from keyboard typing

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I have a textbox for date. It has calender control extender to select date. I want to keep this textbox type protected. i.e. user must enter date by selecting date from calender control only and not allowed to type the date. I tried to keep textbox read-only but it is not solving the purpose..
How can I do so...???

Comment: Why? Clicking half a dozen times on a GUI is likely to take longer then just typing in a date. Let users type dates if they want.

Comment: Why does the readonly attribute not work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm suspect that there is a problem with `ReadOnly` property that textbox loses his state on postback. Try to use `readonly` attribute instead of the `ReadOnly` property. Fot that purpose add following code to Page_PreRender method: `TextBox1.Attributes["readonly"] = "readonly";`

Comment: ..I tried this, but it doesn't work. When textbox loses the focus, the data is lost from textbox

Comment: Do you use server textbox? Do you have some initiating code where Text property cleared? If yes, check does this code executed only on first page load.

Answer (score 1):

try disabled attribute.

```
<input disabled="disabled"></input>
```

If you do that the background color will be gray. To make it white you can do

```
<input disabled="disabled" style="background-color:white"></input>
```

use "style" attribute or css to style it appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `readonly` attribute.

Using `disabled` can be inconvenient if you want to include the input's value as a parameter at `<form>` submission (`disabled` components do not make it to the request when processing the `<form>`).

```
<input readonly="readonly"></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `readonly` attribute isn't working, try setting the `onkeydown` event of the input to return `false`.

```
document.getElementById("input").onkeydown = function(){return false;}
```